# In emacs, how can I pass an argument to a function in a keybinding defintion

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emacs

I want to create a keybinding for funcion *`end-of-line+`* and pass a value of *`-1`* to i. The function is declared as:

- (end-of-line+ &optional n)

The first of the following snippets below, works (*without an arg*). but the other attempts (*with an arg*)  fail... I haven't been able to find an example of a keybinding with args. What's the right way to do this?

```
(global-set-key (kbd  "C-s-E") 'end-of-line+)     ;; Okay!

(global-set-key (kbd  "C-s-E") 'end-of-line+ -1)   ;; Fails 
(global-set-key (kbd  "C-s-E") 'end-of-line+ '-1)  ;; Fails
(global-set-key (kbd  "C-s-E") '(end-of-line+ -1)) ;; Fails
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The idea is just to construct a new function to express your wanted custom behavior (and bind the key to it).

Either with [`lambda`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/lambda.html) ("anonymous", in place) or with [`defun`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defun) (in this case, you give it a name, and you can refer to it with the name).

To define an interactive "command", you need to prepend `(interactive)` to the body.

For example:

```
... (lambda() (interactive) (end-of-line+ -1)) ...
```

or

```
(defun my-end-of-line ()
  "Invoke end-of-line with -1."
  (interactive)
  (end-of-line+ -1))
```

Comment: *@imz:* Thanks, that got it working.  I went with `defun`, and I'll have more of a look at the `lambda` later. I'd better read up on it first.. By the way, it does require `(interactive)`